# Getting eventDelegate to work with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following js:

```
SwitcherView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click li' : 'clickLi',
        'click'    : 'click'
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.liEl = this.$('li');
        console.log(this.liEl);
    },
    clickLi: function(event){
        console.log('click', event);
    },
    click: function(event){
        console.log('click', event);
    }
});

new SwitcherView({el: $('#viewswitcher')});
```

And the following HTML:

```
<div id="viewswitcher" class="block block-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span>Uw kozijn</span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ul class="items">
            <li id="designer-container" class="ui-state-active ui-state-default">
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-designer"></span> Ontwerper
            </li>
            <li id="options-container">
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-options"></span> Kleuropties
            </li>
            <li id="notes-container">
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-notes"></span> Aantekeningen
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the 'click' event does work, but I cant get 'click li' working.

I'm running backbone.js 0.5.3, underscore.js 1.2.1 and jQuery 1.6.4.

Answer (score 1):

When I try your code in [jsFiddle, it works just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianGenisio/M8Qcf/1/).

Dumb question:  Are you testing it by clicking on the first line item (Uw kozijn)?  Because if you are, it is not in the list... it is in it's own DIV so you will not get both events.  If you click on anything else, however, it all works as I would expect.

Comment: Thanks for the response, no I am clicking on the listitems.

Comment: I let this part of the application rest and started working on another part. Created another view, but here, the same problem... Maybe there is a general problem somewhere, but cant seem to find it...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an old jQuery validate library, after updating that library, everything worked as expected!